# How can I secure a Django site

Tags: django

I have a working django site - up-and-live, working just fine. It uses Django's contrib.auth for authentication. It's hosted on Heroku. I would like to set up a clone of this site for demo purposes, but would like to add an extra layer of security around the site, which would be a very simple password-protection. Doesn't have to be bulletproof or unhackable - just enough to put 'muggles' off trying.

This authorisation layer should not in any way interfere with the site auth itself. It's just an outer ring (check once, store access rights in session). Because the site is hosted on Heroku this is not something I can do at the web server level - it has to be part of the app itself.

My nuclear option is to create a django app (working title 'perimeter') which would enforce this, but if anyone knows another way to do this, I would be really grateful.

Core features include:

- Some mechanism for generating short tokens (< 8 chars)
- Some mechanism for logging tokens against an email address
- Prompt users for a token / email combination on first access of site
- Unrestricted access to site thereafter (standard auth model kicks in at that point)

Typical user journey is:

- Bob asks site owner (me) for access to demo site
- I generate a token for Bob and send it him along with the site URL
- Bob clicks on the link, gets redirected to page to input his email and the token
- If the token is valid (expires after X hours / days), store in session, let Bob in.
- If the token is not valid, 403 (/401).

(You may wonder why securing a copy of website that is already public makes any sense. It's because the site is a members-only site, and on the demo version it will be 'auto-enroll' so that people can see what it's like inside the site without having access to the real data. However, I would like to be able to track users on it.)

**[UPDATE: alternative]**

A blunt alternative is to add the token to the URL I send Bob, ignore his email, and simply validate the token itself. That would work so long as Bob always uses the URL in the email.

Comment: How about using OpenID authentication? With some tweaking you could make it accept only logins that have email address (to circumvent OpenID providers which permit fully anonymous accounts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created my own solution to this - meet [Django-Perimeter](https://github.com/hugorodgerbrown/django-perimeter).

This app isn't packaged (yet) so you'll need to clone the source and add it in manually to your own django site, but it does work. It provides the ability to generate access tokens, and then secure access to the site (the entire site, not parts of it) using those tokens.

**[UPDATE]**

This is now available via PyPI - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-perimeter

You can install using `pip install django-perimeter`

Comment: Or you can add it via `pip -e git://github.com/hugorodgerbrown/django-perimeter.git#egg=django_perimiter`